# RuntimeError in Home#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new for Ruby on rails. I have configured the rails in my system(Windows 7).

After Creating the new project in rails (`localhost:3000`) is working fine.
I am try to import the bootstrap in my rails project .
Kindly advise me how to resolve this case.

```
C:\row\dev\mybootstrap>rails g controller home index
C:\row\dev\mybootstrap>rails s
```

Its showing the below error.[image]

Comment: what about installing node js?
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: go to http://nodejs.org/download/ install - restarted the machine

Comment: @GaganGami i am installed the node.js. after that also its showing the same .

Comment: @GaganGami .After installing the Node i will restart my system.Now its woking fine.Thanks for your valuable suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to http://nodejs.org/download/  and install  `nodejs`

**Note:** Don't forget to restart the machine once nodejs is installed.

Answer (score 0):

what about installing node js?

get it from here https://nodejs.org/en/download

Comment: After installing the Node i will restart my system.Now its woking fine.Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: please mark it as the awnser to close this question